# Unable to read serial port with python script but can write

Tags: raspbian, python, usb, serial

I have a microcomputer that is initiated from a pico terminal script establishing a ttyUSB0 and baudrate. The micro is  programmed only to respond to a small list of alphanumeric inputs. Enter x into the terminal and it responds with “how many steps”. Enter for example 500 followed the enter key the micro turns the motor 500 steps and when finished, a “>” appears on the terminal. You can enter y and get the y stepper motor to move and again  return a “>” when finished. My python script runs in another terminal and turns the motor but fails to read the “>” that can be clearly seen on the terminal where the micro was initiated.  It is essential that one be able to detect the “>” to allow the actual move finish before sending another move.
Here is the script which gets the motor to move then returns nothing to the terminal:

```
import serial
import time
import struct
import array as arr
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
ser.baudrate = 38400
x = 200
ser.write(b'x')
time.sleep(0.2)
ser.write(str(x).encode())
time.sleep(0.1)
ser.write(b'\r')
time.sleep(0.5)
while 1:
    while  (ser.inWaiting() > 0):
        try:
             inc = ser.readline().strip()
             print inc
        except serial.SerialException:
             print("no data")
             time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I've edited the code in your post by putting the code tags around it so it shows up better but not touched the text.

Comment: Are you aware the readline waits for the enter key to be pressed unless you tell it to get one character by `.readline(1)` and the strip function needs a character to remove from the front and/or end of the string (e.g. `.strip("A") ) ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there are several issues here.

1. If you have both a terminal program and the python script talking to the port at the same time, only one of them is going to read the data.  Both can write without difficulty.
2. When reading from serial ports, it is often necessary to do some special things:  setting raw mode, setting VTIME and VMIN parameters on the tty, changing other `termios` parameters.  If the line you are trying to read doesn't end in a newline, then you probably need to do this.  (This can be done from the command line using `stty`, but then you need some other special options to prevent a reset on close.)
   As for how this is done in python?  Well, some may be automatic from using serial.Serial.  Some are broken out in serial.Serial.  VTIME is setInterCharTimeout(), but specified in seconds instead of deciseconds.  (Note that python's `read()` is apparently too high level for VTIME to be useful.  pity.)
3. If the line you are trying to read doesn't end in a newline, then you probably do not want to use a "readline" function.  Try "read" instead.

A few code review comments:

1. I suggest `ser.setBaudrate(38400)` instead of `ser.baudrate = 38400`.  The later works by doing the former.  (And apparently python caches what it set instead of reading the device.)
2. I think the two while loops result in using 100% of the CPU.  Without the inner loop, it just blocks in the readline() or read() call.  Without the outer loop, it reads everything there now and then exits.

Edit [more testing, python3 testing, sample code]:

Apparently serial.Serial lost some features between python2 and python3.  In particular, setBaudrate() and several others were removed.

Having tested with python3, and found that VTIME is still defeated.

A simple code sample that works for me (on a simulated serial as that is all I have easily):

```
import serial
 
a = serial.Serial('/dev/hvc0', baudrate=9600)

a.write(b'I am writing to a XEN console, as it is my only convenient serial device\r\n')

while 1:
        b = a.read()
        print (' '.join(( '%02x'%x for x in b )), ':', b)
```

Note that, without proper VTIME (and VMIN) support, I would not recommend python (2 or 3) for anything requiring high performance.  I will also say that it is very unlikely that your application qualifies as requiring high performance, so python is probably OK for you.

As is, I will recommend using `ser.read()` (or equivalent `ser.read(1)`) and `ser.read_all()` rather than trying to do blocking reads of multiple bytes at a time.  Note that that is `read_all` not `readall`.  For instance, in my sample code, the next to last line could be changed to:  `b = a.read() + a.read_all()`

Comment: unfortunately changing ser.baudrate to ser.setBaudrate etc resulted in "serial  Object has no attribute.  The two whiles is the are the result of me trying numerous suggestions from users on the internet. I would be happy to try the simplest script would produce a read result. I have tried other scripts that only have one while statement.  I think i need to learn a bit more before trying to go further. I thank David G and  andyroo